# Free JavaScript/JQuery with Scatter Plot category naming functionality

Tags: javascript, jquery, sharepoint, graph

I am looking for some sort of a free JavaScript/JQuery graphing library that has a lot of scatter plot functionality.  Ultimately, I want to link the plot up with a SharePoint list and drop it in a collaboration site; in such a way it will dynamically update.

My difficulty is that I want a scatter plot where I can change the x-axis and y-axis values to strings (i.e.; x-axis employee names, and y-axis proposal names).

I looked at a whole bunch of libraries (i.e.; flot, Dojox, most of the other options in this thread [JavaScript Chart Library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/119969/javascript-chart-library)), but cannot find this funcitonality in free software (pretty sure Fusion Charts has it if you pay).

I also realize what I am creating (a scatterplot with fixed grid employee & proposal name values) is basically just a chart... however there's nothing--to my knowledge--that will allow me to make a dyanmically updating chart.

Can anyone offer any library tips, or advice?  I am not experienced enough to know of any "work arounds" for this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jqPlot can do it: [jqPlot Home](http://www.jqplot.com/index.php)

[Scatterplot Examples](http://www.jqplot.com/tests/line-charts.php)

Comment: This comment is a good example of why posting links without examples is bad. Scatterplot Examples page no longer works.