# Charts in pure Javascript

Tags: javascript, charts

I want to display some dynamic charts/graphs in my web application.

The current good one in pure javascript is HighCharts which is not free for SAAS apps.

Is there any good, free, pure-javascript chart solution I can use off-the-shelf?

Flash chart solutions don't work on the mobile devices. please suggest good ones.

Comment: Here is a similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/119969/javascript-chart-library

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've used Flot and found it to be ok;

http://code.google.com/p/flot/

Answer (score 0):

Try with Raphael library:

http://raphaeljs.com/

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery [Flot](http://code.google.com/p/flot/) plugin for this.

Answer (score 0):

Check:
http://www.jscharts.com/

www.highcharts.com (if you want it in jQuery)

Hope it helps