# Javascript charting library

Tags: javascript, charts

I'm trying to visualize data like in this spreadsheet https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AhtsNUEmDE6MdE0ybXppcG1jampsVnBfZWpEZm9vbmc .

So I would have columns for each person and hours on the left hand side. And the ability to color the columns like in the spreadsheet.

I know about raphaeljs or flot ... but I'm not seeing in the examples something that fits with what I need.

Or maybe I'm not looking at it the right way.

Any suggestions about what to use and how to best display what I want ?

Thank you.

*EDIT*

http://www.saltycrane.com/blog/2010/03/jquery-flot-stacked-bar-chart-example/
I just found this .. and it seems to have everything I described in the spreadsheet.

Thank you for your answers.

Comment: "ability to color the columns" where are you getting the color data from?

Comment: Have you also looked at Google's Visualization API? [Here's a gallery](http://code.google.com/apis/chart/interactive/docs/gallery.html)

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/119969/javascript-chart-library

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at these links

- [High-charts](http://www.highcharts.com/) - Interactive JavaScript charts for your web pages.
- [Open Flash Chart 2](http://teethgrinder.co.uk/open-flash-chart-2/) - Server side PHP, Perl, Python, Ruby, .NET, Google Web Toolkit and JAVA.
- [Google Charts](http://code.google.com/apis/chart/) - Display live data on your site
- [zingchart](http://www.zingchart.com) - Build Flash or HTML5 charts and graphs with the latest & greatest features and technologies
- [pchart](http://pchart.sourceforge.net/) - pChart is a PHP class oriented framework designed to create aliased charts
- [fusioncharts](http://www.fusioncharts.com/) - It can render over 90 charts and gauges in JavaScript (HTML5) and Flash, along with 550 data-driven maps

Answer (score 2):

Try these ones:

1. http://www.highcharts.com/
2. http://www.jqchart.com/samples/ChartTypes/StackedColumn

Comment: highcharts is quite expensive

Answer (score 1):

I see in your latest comment you found the stacked bar chart will fit your needs. Most JavaScript charting libraries can accommodate that.

This chart shows a list of libraries and the chart types they support -- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_JavaScript_charting_frameworks

Your selection of one of these tools will come down to how you want to render the chart once you've made it, and how you'd like your users to be able to interact with/share the chart.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm .. I think flot will actually do all that I need : http://www.saltycrane.com/blog/2010/03/jquery-flot-stacked-bar-chart-example/ - this is a great example and seems to match what I described.