# Any similar libraries/classes for drawing charts like Google Charts?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, graph, charts

They allow only 2k queries per month which is too little for me. Is there any classes or plugins or something I could use to create similar charts to Google's charts? Thanks.

Comment: I use this one, usefull and pretty [www.jscharts.com](http://www.jscharts.com)

Comment: You have quite a bot of rep, so are not completely useless. What's wrong with [google](https://www.google.com/search?q=javascript+plotting+library)?

Comment: this is also a perfect duplicate of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/119969/javascript-chart-library), which comes up on google search, no less.

Comment: For anyone stumbling upon this question, there are no query limits [(<250k queries/day contact google)](http://googlecode.blogspot.com/2008/03/lifting-limit-on-calls-to-google-chart.html). See my answer below.

Answer (score 2):

Try [Fusion Charts](http://www.fusioncharts.com/), work well with PHP. JQuery try [jQPlot](http://www.jqplot.com)

Answer (score 1):

There are tons of free alternatives!

http://teethgrinder.co.uk/open-flash-chart/ -- flash based 
http://www.highcharts.com/  -- javascript library!
http://www.rgraph.net/  -- javascript library!

and a ton more

[JavaScript Chart Library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/119969/javascript-chart-library)

Answer (score 1):

There are plenty, have a look around. Some I have used before include:

1. [Fusion Charts (Free)](http://www.fusioncharts.com/free)
2. [Highcharts](http://www.highcharts.com/)
3. [Raphael charts](http://raphaeljs.com/)
4. [Rgraph](http://www.rgraph.net/) (HTML5)

All of which are quite different, and all had their pros and cons. I'd say if you were to go for one of them my choice would be fusion charts (especially if you can fork out for the commercial version).

Answer (score 0):

I normally use Highcharts for graphing requirements.

http://www.highcharts.com/

Answer (score 0):

I have used these in the past [dygraphs](http://dygraphs.com/)  .

Answer (score 0):

There are many Javascript graphing libraries but I'd recommend [highcharts](http://www.highcharts.com/demo/) or [flotr2](http://humblesoftware.com/flotr2).

Answer (score 0):

I will just give you the list of chart-things, that i have bookmarked:

- http://www.highcharts.com/ ( this is not free lib, but it might be just what you need )
- http://www.jscharts.com/ ( also not a free thing )
- http://raphaeljs.com/
- http://mbostock.github.com/protovis/
- http://www.liquidx.net/plotkit/
- http://mootools.net/forge/p/milkchart
- http://www.jqplot.com/
- http://thejit.org/
- http://code.google.com/p/flot/
- http://dygraphs.com/
- http://www.globfx.com/ ( not javascript, afaik , and wants $$$ )

Answer (score 0):

Reading the [docs](http://code.google.com/apis/chart/interactive/faq.html#chartapi) the 2k limit you mentioned refers to the [request URI data limit.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/417142/what-is-the-maximum-length-of-a-url) You had me worried there as we're planning on using them soon. 2k queries per month would be a deal breaker for sure.

In 2008, they lifted any query limits. Feel free to use Google charts.

Comment: wow, that's nice then. do I have to have an API for using Google maps?

Comment: Not sure what you're asking here. Check the docs for more info.

Comment: do i need to register somewhere in order to use this api or i can just copy that code from google?

Comment: https://developers.google.com/maps/licensing