# Javascript / JS Charts Framework

Tags: javascript, charts

What would be the best javascript framework for plotting candlestick charts preferably with  trend lines on top of it (and in a way I could customize its look with css, for example) ?

it's for stock_market web application

- It's a business project that involves reading massive data from stock_market and pushing it to the frontend application (web browser) with PUSH (reverse ajax).

Thanks a lot - Bruno Oliveira

Comment: Probably best to do some googling, these type of questions usually get closed

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Recently I had to do the same research. And I found an interesting website, where you can see lot of charts compared by their features, here is the link: http://socialcompare.com/en/comparison/javascript-graphs-and-charts-libraries. I investigated all charts in the list and added information about which of them support candle charts.

Here is the full list of free frameworks:

- [AmCharts](http://amcharts.com) (free with watermark)
- [Dojo Toolkit](http://dojotoolkit.org/features/graphics-and-charting)
- [flot](http://www.flotcharts.org/) (look in plugins)
- [flotr2](http://www.humblesoftware.com/flotr2/index)
- [Google Chart Tools](https://developers.google.com/chart/)
- [jqPlot](http://www.jqplot.com/)
- [Protovis](http://mbostock.github.com/protovis/)

Also there are commercial products like Highcharts/Highstock, but I prefer open source solutions.

As to results of my research, I chose jqPlot. Though it isn't good in terms of performance, but its code is quite straightforward and it is easy to add your own features. For example, you can easily change appearance of candles and draw your own trend lines.
But you should do it by using the canvas HTML element. There is little that can be done by using CSS.

Comment: Amazing. I couldn't have asked for something better! thank you

Comment: We provide a stock charts javascript library at Pizzacharts. It plots candlesticks, OHLC, lines, and much more. Take a look at https://pizzacharts.com/charting for examples and more details.

Answer (score 0):

as you mention this is for stock market data the first one that springs to mind is [highcharts - highstock](http://www.highcharts.com/products/highstock)

Although you do not mention license requirements so it may not be suitable.

Comment: it's fine too, as long as it fits for the need, buying a license is not an impeditive. Ironically, on the top of the page right now I've got an ad that links to a JS stock framework too [AMcharts](http://www.amcharts.com)

However that highcharts js  seems uber! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Simplest thing I remember is Yahoo YUI provide such thing.. 
you can check it out in the following link -

[YUI Charts](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/charts/)

it have some nice example too... 
for eg [Chart with data score polling](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/examples/charts/charts-xhr-polling.html)

as you mentioned you can override YUI's default CSS to make your chart look cool...

Apart from this there are lot of Solutions available.  i found this question ==> [JavaScript Chart Library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/119969/javascript-chart-library)

[Flot](http://www.flotcharts.org/) looks good frame work and one of the example is [Visitors count with zoom](http://people.iola.dk/olau/flot/examples/visitors.html)