# javascript/html charting component with complex features

Tags: javascript, html, charts

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [JavaScript Chart Library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/119969/javascript-chart-library)

We are looking for a javascript charting component with following features:

- mixed line graphs and column graphs
- line graphs have to be stepped (no interpolation)
- column charts must grow downwards from the top of the chart
- multiple value axis
- zooming and sliding

thanks!

Comment: There is already one posted http://stackoverflow.com/questions/119969/javascript-chart-library

Answer (score 0):

Check - http://www.jqchart.com/

Answer (score 0):

All these features are supported by [amcharts.com](http://amcharts.com):
1) mixed line graphs and column graphs:
http://amcharts.com/javascript/column-and-line-chart-mix/

2) Stepped line graph:
http://amcharts.com/javascript/step-line-chart/

3) I have no example of columns from top, but amcharts supports reversed value axes too, so you can simply have this example by changing graph type to "column" in this example:
http://amcharts.com/javascript/line-chart-with-reversed-value-axis/

4) multiple value axes:
http://amcharts.com/javascript/line-chart-with-multiple-value-axes/

5) zooming and sliding:
http://amcharts.com/javascript/line-chart-with-scroll-and-zoom/

All the features you mentioned can be combined in one chart, of course.

Comment: Thanks for posting your answer! Please be sure to read the [FAQ on Self-Promotion](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#promotion) carefully. Also note that it is *required* that you post a disclaimer every time you link to your own site/product.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at TeeChart Javascript too.

Download it here: http://www.steema.com/download/html5

Find the online demos here:
http://www.steema.com/files/public/teechart/html5/v2012.06.1.1/demos/

> - mixed line graphs and column graphs

**Supported**. Just add the series and some values.

> - line graphs have to be stepped (no interpolation)

**Supported**. The Line series can be smoothed, but it isn't by default:
http://www.steema.com/files/public/teechart/html5/v2012.06.1.1/demos/series/line/linepoint.htm

> - column charts must grow downwards from the top of the chart

**Supported**. You can just invert the left axis. In the following example there's a checkbox for it:
http://www.steema.com/files/public/teechart/html5/v2012.06.1.1/demos/series/bar/bar.htm

> - multiple value axis

**Supported**. Find here an example:
http://www.steema.com/files/public/teechart/html5/v2012.06.1.1/demos/axes/multiple_axes.htm

> - zooming and sliding

**Supported**. Draw the rectangle with the left mouse button (from top-left to bottom-right) to zoom in the drawn area. Draw the rectangle on the other direction to zoom out (from bottom-right to top-left). Scroll dragging with the right mouse button.

If you find a problem with any of them, don't hesitate to let us know.