# Link Visualization Library in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, visualization, graph-visualization

I want to show links in my page as network graph consisting of nodes. So please suggest some visualization library or plugin that can be used with javascript or jQuery. i want to show like where links on particular page going.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[mxGraph](https://github.com/jgraph/mxgraph) is an open diagramming library written in JavaScript. We sold it for 10 years, then just open sourced it.

Answer (score 0):

There is a number of javascript libraries out there that you should be able to reuse. A popular open source solution is [d3](http://d3js.org). It is a general purpose visualization library and has good support and examples for visualizing graph like structures.

In a commercial scenario, you might want to take a look at [yFiles](http://www.yworks.com/en/products_yfileshtml_about.html), the latter has the advantage that you can choose from a great number of automatic layout algorithms that can automatically arrange the elements and link routings in your diagrams, which may be necessary if there is a large number of nodes and links that you need to display.

An *outdated* (since it has been closed and does not contain newer solutions) list of libraries is also here:
[JavaScript Chart Library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/119969/javascript-chart-library)

Comment: d3 does not work in IE 7 and IE8. i need some open source libraries

Answer (score 0):

You could also try [sigma.js](http://sigmajs.org/). That is what we're using now.