# Any way to dynamically create flow chart or UML with PHP/MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, uml, flowchart

I've got a process tracking system built with PHP/MySQL and I'd like to provide a graphical representation of the entire process -- a map, more or less.  Each step, tasks, assigned users, and dependencies are stored in MySQL tables and so I have no problem outputting the data in any number of ways, but I'm not sure how I could go about displaying that in a graphical manner.  Processes can be edited by privileged users so I can't just create a process map once and save it -- it needs to be dynamic.

I thought about simply outputting tables or divs but my problem is how to make it responsive to mobile browsers, so I figure a JPG/PNG would be simpler and more platform-independent.  I've seen plenty of LAMP based charting tools but nothing that will create workflows.  The closest I found was yUML (http://yuml.me/) which looks like it would be easy to implement based on a quick review of the syntax, but I'm not running Rails and don't know anything about how to do so.

I also looked into screenshot services (Grabzit, Thumbshots, Websnapr, etc.) but the problem there is that this is a secure site so those services wouldn't be able to gain access.

I'm not looking for anything flashy which is why I thought UML might be a good fit -- I just need to be able to dynamically create process maps based on MySQL data.

Thanks to anyone who can point me in the right direction!

Comment: Question heading :- Any way to dynamically create flow chart or UML    ..................           Description say: - I'm not looking for anything flashy which is why I thought UML might be a good fit ..............................Are you looking for http://www.mysql.com/products/workbench/design/

Comment: No, what I'm looking for is a way to describe the processes (workflows) that the end users have created.  The data for those processes are stored in MySQL but I can query any number of ways to provide the data in a meaningful manner to whatever sort of flowchart API is out there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know of a flow chart API, but there are any number of general purpose chart API's.

Google charts has [examples for org chart](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/orgchart) (among many other chart types).

There are many threads on this kind of thing on SO already:

[JavaScript Chart Library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/119969/javascript-chart-library)
[Graph visualization library in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7034/graph-visualization-code-in-javascript)
etc

Comment: Thanks, that's given me some good places to look -- particularly the Dracula Graph Library (http://www.graphdracula.net/).

Answer (score 0):

I bet one of the best solutions is [D3.js](https://d3js.org/).

> D3.js is a JavaScript library for producing dynamic, interactive data
> visualizations in web browsers. It makes use of Scalable Vector
> Graphics, HTML5, and Cascading Style Sheets standards.
>
> —*[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/D3.js)*

You can find many [examples here](https://observablehq.com/@d3/gallery) to fit what you are looking for, especially its very well documented [API reference](https://github.com/d3/d3/blob/master/API.md). Also has an incredible [wiki](https://github.com/d3/d3/wiki) (in many languages), greatest [tutorials](https://github.com/d3/d3/wiki/Tutorials) and some [plugins](https://github.com/d3/d3/wiki/Plugins).