# Adding Google Charts or Similar to Chrome Packaged App

Tags: google-chrome, google-visualization, google-chrome-app

I have a Chrome Packaged App that I want to be able to graph data for the user. I would ideally like to interface with something along the lines of the Charts/Visualization API, but I'm trying to find a solution that will work offline, possibly through integration with other apps or within my app specifically. Is there a way to insert a Google Chart or something very similar into my packaged app? Is there an API or feature I am unaware of that would make this feasible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately the Google Charts library cannot be downloaded for inclusion in a packaged app due to their terms and conditions:

> Sorry; our terms of service do not allow you to download and save or host the google.load or google.visualization code.
>   - [Google Charts FAQ](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/faq#localdownload)

That said, there are many excellent Javascript libraries that are available for download which you could include with your packaged app and use as if they were included from a remote source.

[This stack overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/119969/javascript-chart-library) should help you decide between the various options. You should then download the Javascript files for the library you chose and place them within the folder of your packaged app and then use them like any local Javascript that you've written.

Comment: That link recommends d3, which I highly recommend.  If you are using angular for the controller of your packaged app, there are some great directives that help work with angular and d3.  https://github.com/robinboehm/angular-d3-directives