# what is the top chart javascript library can i use free in my commercial webapp?

Tags: charts

i am working in site that generate Code ([chart builder](http://charts.livegap.com)) For Charts.
it's now working with library (chartnew.js). but i want to extend with  new chart library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used a couple of Javascript charts libraries over the years.

RaphaelJS is my best pick.
However, take a look to the following list provided from that question:

[JavaScript Chart Library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/119969/javascript-chart-library)

- [RaphaelJS](http://raphaeljs.com/)
- [FlotChart](http://www.flotcharts.org/)
- [ExtJS](http://dev.sencha.com/extjs/5.0.0/examples/index.html)
- [zingchart](http://www.zingchart.com/)
- [Protovis](http://vis.stanford.edu/protovis/)
- [D3 JS](http://d3js.org/)
- [Rickshaw](http://code.shutterstock.com/rickshaw/)
- [JQPlot](http://www.jqplot.com/)
- [TechOctave charts](http://techoctave.com/charts/)
- [RGraph](http://www.rgraph.net/)
- [DojoToolkit](http://livedocs.dojotoolkit.org/dojox/charting)

Answer (score 2):

In the future, you may want to post questions like this in softwarerecs.stackexchange.com. This question will likely be closed as it violates the policies of this particular site.

However, I'll answer your question here just in case. There are quite a few JavaScript charting libraries out there for you to use in your web app, all with various pricing structures - Highcharts, Fusioncharts, amCharts, and the one that I'm suggesting - [ZingChart](http://www.zingchart.com). ZingChart can be licensed, but the entire library can be used in your web app for free with a small logo in the bottom right corner. It's incredibly easy to implement and has every chart type and feature you  need.

You can view live demos on our [Kitchen Sink](http://www.zingchart.com/demos/kitchen-sink-demo) to get a feel for the library. I'm on the ZingChart team and we're available for any questions you might have at support@zingchart.com!

Answer (score 0):

You could use flotcharts. This is a jquery pluggin

http://www.flotcharts.org/